# does Cassandra's CCM tool only support one keyspace?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1, ccm

I am working with a cluster I created with ccm.  We are using 3 tables in 2 keyspaces, so 6 tables in total.  I was having a problem that it let me create one table in one keyspace and 2 in the other but even when I removed my

```
IF NOT EXISTS
```

check then it would give me an error saying it already exists.  It seems that the create is ignoring the fact that these are supposed to be in 2 separate keyspaces;

These are the same cql script files that we run against our dev cloud Cassandra cluster, so I know its not an issue with the scripts.  That, and the create statements are pretty simple and straightforward.

So does CCM only support one keyspace?  If so, that seems like a pretty big limitation and makes it much much less useful, if we can even use it at all for our local dev and testing purposes.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you switching keyspaces in between? To me it seems like an issue with one keyspace being set and then never being changed later

Comment: Yes, I am switching them.  Our scripts are fully qualified like so:  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_keyspace.my_table1 ( ....);

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: No, CCM doesn't support only one keyspace.

CCM doesn't have any restrictions at all built into it. Under the covers it is just a set of python scripts for configuring and launching a cassandra cluster on a single machine.